# Error when using 'Keypair.generate' from "@solana/web3.js" - SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode

Tags: web3.js

New to solana, going through my first tut.

The first task is to generate a keypair from the web3.js package.

my file --

```
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";

const keypair = Keypair.generate();

console.log(`The public key is: `, keypair.publicKey.toBase58());
console.log(`The secret key is: `, keypair.secretKey);
console.log(`✅ Finished!`);
```

my output --

```
SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:139:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:236:14)     
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:67:21)
```

I don't think this is a solana error but the stuff I'm finding online about this is pretty obscure and less than helpful.   Does anyone know why I'm getting this.

here is how I'm calling the file -

```
npx esrun genKeyPair.ts
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "generate-keypair",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@solana-developers/node-helpers": "^1.2.1",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.87.6",
    "esrun": "^3.2.26",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is for sure not a Solana specific issue, but rather a JS/TS related issue. What is your local setup for this? I see you using esrun but no other details here.

Comment: do you have the npm packages installed?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a typescript issue. Try turning off `strict` mode via your tsconfig.json

Comment: Yes so I've followed this step by step

https://www.soldev.app/course/intro-to-cryptography

Comment: what line of code is throwing this `octal` error? I just tried running this locally and it runs fine, no errors. can you share your tsconfig?

Comment: I've just reinstalled typescript local to the folder - same error

This is the stack trace -

SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.

    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:139:18)

    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:236:14)

    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:67:21)

Comment: So very odd to me. Can you publish everything to a repo you and share the link?

Comment: https://github.com/4cody/sol

Comment: @4cody sounds like this is a warning from some node internal code, in the ESM loader `node:internal/modules/esm/loader:236:14` - what version of node.js are you using? Can you try upgrading to the current latest 18x or 20.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Upgrade your node.js**

The error is in node's inbuilt modules (anything that starts with `node:` is code that comes with node.js itself). [There's an octal escape sequence like `\033`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039567/octal-escape-sequences-are-not-allowed-in-template-strings) in one of these inbuilt files and it shouldn't be there. In short: there was a bug in node.js itself.

But your code works fine on node 20.6.0

```
% node -v
v20.6.0
```

Running it:

```
% npx esrun genKey.ts
✅ Generated keypair!
```

Comment: This somewhat fixed my issue.  I'm still getting the octal error but I'm able to see an expected printout of the desired console log ---  "generated keypair"
Thanks

Comment: Interesting - what does `node -v` return?

Comment: it returns v20.6.0