'Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode' error when generating keypair
I started Solana and web 3 dev recently
Have been having this issue for like 3 days, tried checking online for solutions and nothing.
Please help anyone
CODE
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";

const keypair = Keypair.generate();

console.log(`The public key is: `, keypair.publicKey.toBase58());
console.log(`The secret key is: `, keypair.secretKey);

Error Output
file:///C:/Users/USER/Documents/SuperTeam/A.%20dApp%20development/1.%20Cryptography%20and%20the%20Solana%20Network/generate-keypair/node_modules/.bin/esrun-1717427433423.tmp.mjs:7
const __esrun_fileUrl = __esrun_url.pathToFileURL("\Users\USER\Documents\SuperTeam\A. dApp development\1. Cryptography and the Solana Network\generate-keypair\node_modules.bin\esrun-1717427433423.tmp.mjs");
SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.
    at compileSourceTextModule (node:internal/modules/esm/utils:337:16)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:163:18)
    at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:429:14)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:435:30)
    at async ModuleJob._link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:106:19)

Node.js v22.1.0

Used npx esrun generate-keypair.ts to initiate

This seems really similar to https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8917/error-when-using-keypair-generate-from-solana-web3-js-syntaxerror-octal but you're using a current node.js, which is why I didn't mark it as a duplicate. Do check out the answers on that page though. The error isn't Solana related, but rather from node.js itself.

Ok thanks, I'll check it out

i am got the same problem
i think the problem at esrun
and i change to ts-node and works
this is my package.json
"@solana/web3.js": "^1.95.0",
"@types/node": "^20.14.10",
"dotenv": "^16.4.5",
"ts-node": "^10.9.2",
"typescript": "^5.5.3"

